# How to recalculate a skeleton's pose (all PoseBone matrices) via python without a full scene update?

Tags: python, animation, armature

I'm working on a script to do some retargeting of an animation library to a new figure, and I've encountered a performance issue I don't know how to optimize away easily. My script loops through an animation using `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)`, and makes changes to the matrix and matrix_basis properties of a figure's PoseBones. There is one iterative step in the algorithm where I want to update a PoseBone, and then have the full pose recalculated so that the matrices of bones that are descendents reflect the change.

Calling `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` is suggested in response to a number of similar questions, but this updates a lot more than I need it to, with a crippling execution time cost when there is a high-resolution figure using the affected Armature.

One thought I had was to temporarily remove the Armature modifier at the start of the script, and replace it at the end, but before I try workarounds like this I wanted to ask if there is simply an API call I can't find to recalculate only the pose matrices of the bones of an Armature without forcing Blender to update all the affected meshes?